# phantomjs + jquery: returns empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

This webpage (test.html):

```
<p id="test">bla</p>
```

And this js code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log("Message: "+msg);
};

page.open("http://localhost/test.html", function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                console.log($("#test").text());
            });
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Result:

```
Message:
```

Does anybody know Why it doesn't display the text content of p when I run it with phantomjs?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822126/phantomjs-page-onconsolemessage-doesnt-log-warnings

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one:

```
console.log($("#test").val());
```